# Render a minimized JSON from a pretty JSON template in Go

Tags: go

**TL;DR:** how do I idiomatically strip whitespace and line breaks from a JSON string in Go?

So I have a pretty JSON template in a file in my repo (`templates/simple.template`):

```
{
  "key": "{{ .Value }}"
}
```

It has nice line breaks and indentations so it's easy to read and edit.

Here's a simplified code I use these simplified lines to render this template:

```
import "text/template"

...

tmpl, err = template.ParseFiles("templates/simple.template")
var buf bytes.Buffer
tmpl.Execute(&buf, struct{ Value string }{Value: "some string"})

return buf.String(), nil
```

My resulting JSON is *still pretty* when I log it:

```
{
  "key": "some string"
}
```

But of course this string includes all the line breaks and identations, and I don't want this in my HTTP payloads (or for production logs for that matter):

[image]

How do I achieve both:

1. Have a pretty template in my repo
2. Render this template into a slim JSON that I can log and use in my HTTP payloads

Comment: You can unmarshal and marshal it. You are treating json as string, not as a data structure. A template is not a good mechanism to produce JSON data. For one thing, you can produce invalid JSON because template engine will not escape special characters.

Comment: [json.Compact](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Compact) does exactly what you want.